# ASP.NET MVC 4 Model Encapsulation Rendering View Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, entity-framework-4

I need to pass multiple models to a View and I would like the View to be strongly typed (so if I can help it I would like to do this without the use of passing each one of my models to a ViewBag).

```
Public Class TestModels
    Public Class TestDetail

        Public firstModel As firstModelHere ' An entity
        Public secondModel As secondModelHere ' An entity

        Sub New()
            firstModel = Nothing
            secondModel = Nothing
        End Sub

    End Class
End Class
```

Which I have in its own independent file in a directory for models. I pass the encapsulated model to my view like so:

```
@ModelType Website.TestModels.TestDetail
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.firstModel.userName)
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.secondModel.lastName)
```

And I set firstModel and secondModel in my controller and pass the model to view. When I go to compile my project I get dozens of errors (see below), how can I fix this? I simply want to be able to access multiple models that are encapsulated in another class from my Views. Thanks in advance.

```
Error   134 'ViewBag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Error   129 'Context' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Error   138 'Layout' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Error   131 sub 'Execute' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am missing a coding trick or pattern, but why do you have the class 'TestDetail', inside of the class 'TestModels'?

If you are simply looking to pass multiple models to a view, I would make single view model, with a property for each entity that you want to pass to the view.

**View Model** - Used to encapsulate the models you want to access in your view

```
Public Class TestModel   
    Public Property FirstModel As FirstEntity ' An entity
    Public Property SecondModel As SecondEntity ' An entity
End Class
```

**Controller action**

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ' Create models to pass to the view.
    Dim a As New FirstModel
    Dim b As New SecondModel

    ' Create model to pass the models in.
    Dim model As New TestModel
    With model
        .firstModel = a
        .secondModel = b
    End With

    Return View(model)
End Function
```